# Crear formulario html dependiendo el número de columnas de una tabla mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli

Buen Día, estoy haciendo un sistema de clasificación de objetos, cada clasificación tiene diferentes parámetros que lo describen, cuando un usuario da de alta una nueva clasificación creo una nueva tabla con el nombre de la clasificación y los datos que en ella va a almacenar, como el nombre, costo, medidas, etc.
En ello no tengo ningún problema.

Mi pregunta es, si es posible que, cuando un usuario vaya a meter un item X en la tabla de clasificación Y se despliegan en un formulario las columnas (ya que no las puedo escribir directo en código porque no conozco los valores) ejemplo:

El usuario da de alta la clasificación "Computadora", con el cual los parámetros que va a pedir son: "Marca","Modelo","RAM","Almacenamiento" (Mi formulario es dinámico así que es indefinido el número de valores a solicitar, ya que van agregando más y más).

Y se crea la tabla "Computadora" con las columnas "Marca", "Modelo", "RAM" y "Almacenamiento"

Al momento de dar de alta una nueva computadora quisiera que se desplegara un formulario dependiendo las columnas dentro de la tabla "Computadora"
Ej:

```
<form action="enviar.php" method="Post">   
  <input type="text" name="Marca" />  
  <input type="text" name="Modelo" />  
  <input type="text" name="RAM" />  
  <input type="text" name="Almacenamiento" />  
</form>
```

Generar con un while o foreach inputs dependiendo el número de las columnas y posteriormente los datos insertarlos en la tabla "Computadora" con php

¿Esto es posible y si es así me podrían dar un pequeño ejemplo?
Gracias y saludos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> hola :) si entendí bien tu problema, con el siguiente codigo puedes tener algún resultado al respecto, segun el tipo de conexion a tu DDBB es la sintaxis con la cual debes obtener el nombre de columnas, en este caso es con el metodo MySQLi.

segun el siguiente enlace... http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli-result.fetch-fields.php

```
<?php

function myinit() {
    $host = "localhost";
    $user = "user";
    $passwd = "pass";
    $db_name = "db_name";
    $db = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $passwd, $db_name);
    return $db;
}

#conexion DB
$db = myinit();

$query = "SELECT marca, modelo, ram, almacenamiento FROM computadora";
$items = $db->query($query);

#nombre de columnas según consulta realizada
$column = $items->fetch_fields();

$items->free();

$html = '';
$html .= '<form action="enviar.php" method="Post">';

#Recorremos y generamos los input
#print_r($column);
foreach ($column as $key => $col) {

    $html .= '<label>'.$col->name.'</label> ======>';
    $html .= '<input type="text" name="'.$col->name.'"/></br></br>';
}

$html .= '</form>';


echo $html;


?>
```

> Saludos.

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias Elias!
Me ha funcionado de maravilla

Comment: Genial men :), Saludos.